# Saving to and importing from a .txt file, causes the data to be overwritten

Tags: java, listview, javafx, save, overwrite

I want to be able to save my Card objects into the "CardsColleciton.txt" file (either by typing into it or by hard-coding them) and then load those objects into my list testingList so that I can display them correctly.However, I've tried a ton of things but I can't seem to figure out why the following two problems happen:

1) Whenever I write to the .txt file either by hard-coding or by typing in it,my code loads them just fine but after closing the program, the data gets deleted and I have to start over.

2) If I hard-code the objects, they do show up in my list but when I write normally to the .txt file ,the code says they were loaded(and they were, testinglist's size does increase) but it doesn't display them on the listView.

Hopefully someone in here can help me figure out those two.

PS: I have read many other similar posts about the 1st problem but none of them solved mine.

Here are my .java files:

Card.java:

```
package com.spdesigns.dokkancardspreview.model;

 import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class Card {

private String mName;
private String mDescription;
private Image mMainImage;
private Image mSecondaryImage;

public Card(String name, String description, String mainImagePath, String secondaryImagePath) {
    mName = name;
    mDescription = description;
    mMainImage = new Image(mainImagePath);
    mSecondaryImage = new Image(secondaryImagePath);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return mName + " | " + mDescription;
}

public Image getmMainImage() {
    return mMainImage;
}

public Image getmSecondaryImage() {
    return mSecondaryImage;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}
}
```

controller -> home.java:

```
package com.spdesigns.dokkancardspreview.controllers;

import com.spdesigns.dokkancardspreview.model.Card;

import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
 import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class home implements Initializable {

/*private Card hit = new Card("Hit","Expanding Possibility",
        "/images/hit_main.jpg", "/images/hit_secondary.jpg");*/
// This is how I "hard-code" the object so that the 2nd issue does not occur
  private Card goku = new Card("Goku SSJ3","Everlasting Legend",
             "/images/gokussj3_main.jpg", "/images/gokussj3_secondary.jpg");

private boolean clickedAgain = false;

@FXML
private Button arrowButton;
@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

@FXML
private ImageView arrow;

@FXML
private ListView listView;

protected List<Card> testingList = new ArrayList<Card>();

protected ListProperty<Card> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<Card>();


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    //addCard(hit);
      addCard(goku);
    //testingList.add("test2");

    listView.itemsProperty().bind(listProperty);
    // wrapping our list in an observable list and then pass that observableList to the ListProperty isntance
    listProperty.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(testingList));

    // Handle listView selection changes
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        Card currentlySelectedCard = listProperty.get(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        System.out.printf("ListView item clicked! Value retrieved: %s\n", currentlySelectedCard);
        imageView.setImage(new Image(currentlySelectedCard.getmMainImage().impl_getUrl()));
        arrow.setVisible(true);
        arrowButton.setVisible(true);
    }));

    arrow.translateYProperty().set(283f);
    arrowButton.translateYProperty().set(283f);
    arrow.setRotate(180);
    arrow.setVisible(false);
    arrowButton.setVisible(false);
}

public void handleShowDetails(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("Button Clicked!");
    Card currentlySelectedCard = listProperty.get(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    if (clickedAgain) {
        imageView.setImage(new Image(currentlySelectedCard.getmMainImage().impl_getUrl()));
        arrow.setRotate(180);
        clickedAgain = false;
    } else {
        imageView.setImage(new Image(currentlySelectedCard.getmSecondaryImage().impl_getUrl()));
        arrow.setRotate(360);
        clickedAgain = true;
    }
}

// Saving
public void exportTo(String fileName) {
    try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fos);
    ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < testingList.size() - 1; i++) {
            writer.printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", testingList.get(i).getName(), testingList.get(i).getDescription(),
                    testingList.get(i).getmMainImage().impl_getUrl(), testingList.get(i).getmSecondaryImage().impl_getUrl());
            System.out.println(testingList.get(i).toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.printf("Problem saving: %s/n", fileName);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Loading
public void importFrom(String fileName) {
    try (
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    ) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] args = line.split("\\|");
            this.addCard(new Card(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]));
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.printf("Problem loading: %S\n", fileName);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (Card card : testingList) {
        System.out.printf("%s loaded\n", testingList.get(i).toString());
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Loading Successful!");
}

public void addCard(Card card) {
    testingList.add(card);
}

// DEBUG purposes
public void printTestingList() {
    for (Card card : testingList) {
        System.out.println(card.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Main.java:

```
package com.spdesigns.dokkancardspreview;

import com.spdesigns.dokkancardspreview.controllers.home;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

private home controller;
private File file = new File("CardsCollection.txt");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/home.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    controller = loader.getController();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Dokkan Battle Card Preview");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 700));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    // Loading cards
    primaryStage.show();
    try {
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        controller.importFrom("CardsCollection.txt");
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("Error loading file!");
        npe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//TODO:sp Fix when closisng the app-saving, the .txt file gets reseted
@Override
public void stop() {
    System.out.println("App is closing!");
    // Saving before exiting
    try {
        controller.exportTo("CardsCollection.txt");
        System.out.println("Saving was successful!\n");
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("Problem saving file!");
        npe.printStackTrace();
    }
    controller.printTestingList();
   // System.out.println(file.);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Well first of all I would recommend to write in a csv file instead of just a plain txt file as they are pretty easy to handle and almost the same. Also there are tons of API´s you could use for csv files.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim , I created a test project so that I could use a csv file but the problem where everything in the file gets deleted after the program ends is still present...I'll keep on searching though but if you know what causes it let me know! Thanks in advance. EDIT: this issue occurs when I write to the file once and then comment out the lines that write to the file, leaving just the code for reading from it.Is that wrong?

Comment: Does the file get deleted or is just the content disappearing? Well I wouldn´t comment the lines out that write to the file. Try to split the reading and writting into different methods. What API are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderHeim I've already splitted them and no the file does not get deleted just the content.Yeah you're actually right about not commenting out the write method's calling. I'm using commons-lang3-3.6 with the opencsv version 4 API

Comment: Some asides: 1. Please use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). It makes it harder for Java programmers to read your code if you don't follow these conventions. 2. Don't use private API. You should be getting a compiler warning on `impl_getUrl()`, for example (what is wrong with `imageView.setImage(currentlySelectedImage.getMainImage())`???). 3. Don't catch Null pointer exceptions. Either code around them (`if (xxx != null) {...}`) or let them propagate up. NPEs are indications of programming errors.

Answer (score 0):

This here is part of a program I've written a couple months ago, try those methods to access your csv file:

```
    // Writes to CSV File
    private void writeCSV(ArrayList<String[]> newContent){

        CSVWriter writer;

        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(this.path), ';', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
            writer.writeAll(newContent);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CSVFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }  
    }

    // Reads from CSV File
    private ArrayList<String> readCSV(){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList();

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.path));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                ret.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

This uses for writing, the API openCSV and for reading just a normal BufferedReader (no special imports needed).

The `writeCSV()` is able to overwrite the whole content of a `.csv` file. Each String[] represents a row and each element in that Array a column for that row. In case you just want to modify the content in the File you will need to first read to `.CSV` file and then modify the ArrayList.

Note: `readCSV()` returns just a ArrayList of strings, so you need to split the String with ";" in order to get access to each column.

I hope that´s not too confusing^^

Answer (score 0):

Your `addCard()` method is adding to the underlying list, not the `ListProperty`. As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) for the method you use to create the observable list

> Creates a new observable array list and adds a content of collection col to it.

In other words, a new list is created which initially contains the elements in the provided list. Subsequent changes to the collection you pass will not change the observable list.

You probably just need a single observable list here: there is no need to create an additional "plain" list and no need for a `ListProperty`:

```
public class Home implements Initializable {

    private Card goku = new Card("Goku SSJ3","Everlasting Legend",
                 "/images/gokussj3_main.jpg", "/images/gokussj3_secondary.jpg");

    private boolean clickedAgain = false;

    @FXML
    private Button arrowButton;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @FXML
    private ImageView arrow;

    @FXML
    private ListView listView;

    private ObservableList<Card> cards = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        addCard(goku);

        listView.setItems(cards);

        // Handle listView selection changes
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(((observable, oldCard, newCard) -> {

            System.out.printf("ListView item clicked! Value retrieved: %s\n", newCard);
            imageView.setImage(newCard.getmMainImage());
            arrow.setVisible(true);
            arrowButton.setVisible(true);
        }));

        arrow.translateYProperty().set(283f);
        arrowButton.translateYProperty().set(283f);
        arrow.setRotate(180);
        arrow.setVisible(false);
        arrowButton.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void handleShowDetails(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Button Clicked!");
        Card currentlySelectedCard = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (clickedAgain) {
            imageView.setImage(currentlySelectedCard.getmMainImage());
            arrow.setRotate(180);
            clickedAgain = false;
        } else {
            imageView.setImage(currentlySelectedCard.getmSecondaryImage());
            arrow.setRotate(360);
            clickedAgain = true;
        }
    }

    // Saving
    public void exportTo(String fileName) {
        try (
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fos);
        ) {
            for (Card card : cards) {
                // TODO should make image locations properties of card
                // to implement this properly
                writer.printf("%s|%s|%s|%s\n", card.getName(), card.getDescription(),
                        card.getmMainImage().impl_getUrl(), card.getmSecondaryImage().impl_getUrl());
                System.out.println(card.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.printf("Problem saving: %s/n", fileName);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Loading
    public void importFrom(String fileName) {
        try (
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        ) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] args = line.split("\\|");
                this.addCard(new Card(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]));
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.printf("Problem loading: %S\n", fileName);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (Card card : testingList) {
            System.out.printf("%s loaded\n", testingList.get(i).toString());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Loading Successful!");
    }

    public void addCard(Card card) {
        cards.add(card);
    }

    // DEBUG purposes
    public void printTestingList() {
        for (Card card : cards) {
            System.out.println(card.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Your first issue isn't quite clear to me. If you mean you want to append cards to the existing file when you save, then you need to replace

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
```

with

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
```